# Windows 10: How to change Loopback's NetworkCategory from Public to Private?

Tags: windows-10

On my Windows 10 laptop, I have 2 interfaces:

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetConnectionProfile

```
Name             : Unidentified network
InterfaceAlias   : Loopback
InterfaceIndex   : 16
NetworkCategory  : Public
IPv4Connectivity : NoTraffic
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic

Name             : BoonMIFI_149E
InterfaceAlias   : Wi-Fi
InterfaceIndex   : 11
NetworkCategory  : Public
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic
```

I have been trying to change the loopback's NetworkCategory from Public to Private using secpol.msc:
`Network List Manager Policies` > `Unidentified networks` > `Private` but this doesn't seem to change it.

How do I change the loopback's NetworkCategory from Public to Private?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by experimentation:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-NetConnectionProfile -InterfaceIndex 16 -NetworkCategory Private
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetConnectionProfile


Name             : Unidentified network
InterfaceAlias   : Loopback
InterfaceIndex   : 16
NetworkCategory  : Private
IPv4Connectivity : NoTraffic
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic

Name             : BoonMIFI_149E
InterfaceAlias   : Wi-Fi
InterfaceIndex   : 11
NetworkCategory  : Public
IPv4Connectivity : Internet
IPv6Connectivity : NoTraffic
```

However, this [does not persist across reboots](https://superuser.com/questions/1441412/windows-10-set-netconnectionprofile-permanent) (and reverts back to Public).

Also, it's strange that secpol.msc doesn't seem to work while PS command does.